# Is there anything more after I finish the story?

Tags: vector-2

I'm playing Vector 2, and I have completed the main story (as far as I can tell). At this point I'm playing simply to see what breaks first - the game or my interest.

> I have completed the story to the point where I found the "alternate exit" to the facility, and the director told me to "continue the testing as planned". I have unlocked the helmet, gloves, boots and belt, and am just looking to finish upgrading and finding all of the "upgrades".

I'm at a point now where no matter what I do, I gain so many points that all of my equipment has more than full charges, so there's almost no way I can lose.

Is there anything more to unlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little information about Vector 2 at this point, outside of the [wiki entries](https://nekkivector.fandom.com/wiki/Vector_Wiki#Legacy) for the "Legacy" of the original game.

> The game received a 2016 sequel titled as Vector 2 that continues the storyline of the original game. The protagonist from the first installment was eventually captured by security forces at the last stage of the location Technology Park. But instead of killing him, the security forces decided to test and use his skills and stamina with the featured new equipment in a secret research laboratory/facility. In the original sequel, the final story is not yet revealed stating that the game is still ongoing because Nekki is working on games such as the series of Shadow Fight.

Additional levels *have* been developed at this point, as the player enters a maintenance area of the Facility, however it appears that this is where the development for the game has stopped. Very few updates have been released, and Shadow Flight is constantly being advertised with in the Vector 2 game.